# sgx: There are zero EPC sections

Tags: qemu, kvm, sgx

I use i7-8700 and asus tuf z370 motherboard now.
I already changed SGX option to "software controlled"(there are no option "enabled")
I tried to use kvm-sgx [following this document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/virtualizing-intel-software-guard-extensions-with-kvm-and-qemu)
I compiled kernel to 5.0.0 and I checked and changed grub to use 5.0.0+ compiled kernel for kvm-sgx
but when I do 
`dmesg | grep sgx`
It shows `sgx: There are zero EPC sections.`
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ASUS board only support software required but this work need enabled option. Do not use that motherboard!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there are support from intel.
In gihub intel/sgx_software_enable repo
You can make and run sgx_enable executable